# Should I throw away the return value of boost::python::exec?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost, boost-python

I'm writing a program with C++ and `boost::python`, and it seems very strange to me that `boost::python::exec` returns anything at all. For example, in the [docs here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/embedding.html#embedding.boost_python_exec_hpp.function_exec), it says:

> ### Effects
>
> Execute Python source code from code in the context specified by the dictionaries globals and locals.
>
> ### Returns
>
> An instance of object which holds the result of executing the code.

And yet the documentation for [python 3's `exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function says that:

> *The return value is `None`.*

So what's the point of returning anything if the function always returns none? Why not just make it a `void` function, or even better yet, have it return a python error if something goes wrong? Or maybe, I'm just misunderstanding the documentation, and there is something useful in there after all. Which is why I'm asking this question.

As I was trying to figure this out, I tried this sample program:

```
#include <boost\python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    Py_Initialize();

    object main_module = import("__main__");
    object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            std::cout << ">>> ";
            std::string comm;
            std::getline(std::cin, comm);
            if (comm == "exit")
                break;
            object bar = exec(comm.c_str(), main_namespace);
            if (bar.is_none())
                std::cout << "None\n";
        }
        catch (error_already_set const &)
        {
            PyErr_Print();
        }
    }
}
```

And it seems like `exec` never returned an object that isn't `None`.

So is there *ever*, under *any* circumstance a reason to keep around the return value of a `boost::python::exec` call, or should I just always throw it away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of a void function in Python is one with no return value. If you attempt to assign the result of a void function, the result will always be `None`.

Boost::Python seems to follow this in their implementation of `py::exec`, although this is no surprise as even the CPython `PyRun_String` function that `py::exec` calls returns a `PyObject` that is always `None`.

So to answer your question, yes you can ignore the return value.